# External Doubly Linked-list Iterator c++

Tags: c++

I made a doubly linked list. In my main, I need to use an external List Iterator that has a constructor that takes a list. This is what I have so far:

```
struct ListIterator : List {
    Node* cur = head;

    ListIterator(List* list) {
        this -> list = list;
    }

    bool hasNext() {
        return (cur -> next) != nullptr;
    }

    int next() {
        return list.at(cur -> next);
    }
};
```

This is my main:

```
List list1;

list1.append('I');
list1.append('D');
list1.append('F');
list1.append('G');
ListIterator it(list1);

while (it.hasNext()) {
   cout << it.next();
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use hasNext() and next() to display all the nodes in a list. I'm confused on how to create a constructor that takes a list and use the function in ListIterator struct. Any tips and hints would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why does this look more like Java than C++? :P  C++ has certain idioms for containers and iterators. Use them.

Comment: Does your even compile? The statement `ListIterator it(list1);` is not passing pointer to List in the constructor.

Comment: Isn't the name of the List a pointer?

Comment: Also, you do realize that your `ListIterator` inherits from your `List` class. Is that intended? It doesn't seem right to me. Also, agree with @cHao that this looks awfully familiar to Java and does not follow the way C++ handles iterators.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis Hmm... It is C++ for sure. I figured I need List because that's where I include head and tail pointers. Maybe I don't need it.

Comment: @Jake: If your list type is a `struct` too, and you haven't used any access modifiers, then you don't need to inherit to see those members -- they're public by default. (Even if you'd made everything private, though, there are better ways than inheritance to provide access without leaving everything wide open.) Unless you can say a `ListIterator` is a list in and of itself, inheritance is the wrong relationship.

Comment: tutorial https://pastebin.com/DXunz58Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be heavily influenced by Java (or perhaps even C#). It's not a bad thing, you just need to learn the ins and outs of C++.

For your first problem: in C++, there is a clear distinction between values, references and pointers. When you declare an instance of your `List` class as follows:

```
List list1;
```

that is actually a value. The instance exists on the stack and will be properly disposed off (the destructor will be called) once the scope is ended.

If you now were to initialize a second list as follows:

```
List list2 = list1;
```

that is also a value, and it will copy the entire list (the copy constructor or assignment operator will be called). Now `list1` and `list2` are two distinct list instances and modifying one will not affect the other.

Anyhow, to get a pointer to a list, you need the following syntax:

```
List *listPtr1 = &list1;
```

As it is a pointer, an indirection, copying it will not copy the underlying structure:

```
List *listPtr2 = listPtr1; // Will also point to list1
```

---

While using the proper syntax will solve your immediate problem, it doesn't properly address the odd iterator implementation.

In C++, iterators either point to a single element in a container or they point *past-the-end*. An iterator typically does not know if the end of the container is reached by itself; instead, it needs to be compared to this *past-the-end* iterator.

Containers typically define a [`begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) method that returns an iterator to the first element, and an [`end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) method that returns an iterator to *past-the-end*.

Iterating over a container typically happens using the following prototype:

```
for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); ++it)
{
    // To access the element, you need to dereference the iterator:
    std::cout << "The current value is :" << *it << std::endl;
}
```

In this regard, iterators behave much like pointers to the elements. There's no need for the clunky `next` and `hasNext` methods. You simply get an iterator to the start of your container, make sure to stop iterating once it points to *past-the-end*, and increment it when you want to go to the next element.

A container that properly defines the `begin` and `end` methods can also be used in a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (auto &element : container)
{
    std::cout << "The current value is :" << element << std::endl;
}
```

---

I understand it is fun and very educational to implement your own containers. I reinvented my fair share of wheels just to understand how things work exactly, so nothing wrong with that. But I would advice you to perhaps play around with standard C++ containers first, get the hang of the major differences between C++ and languages like Java and C# and then have another go at the exercise.